# WCF Service Logging Encrypted Data

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-security, x509certificate

I am having a WCF service secured by X509, a client and they are working as expected.

I am trying to log the message at serverside and view the decrypted messages. But what I am getting in the log is encrypted message.

I have set logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true". Please help me find the issue with my configuration.

Following is the configuration:

```
 <system.serviceModel>

.. service definition here...

<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="false"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
       maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
      switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing"
      propagateActivity="true" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
      switchValue="Verbose">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="Microsoft.IdentityModel"
      switchValue="Verbose">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
  <sharedListeners>
  <add name="xml"
     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
     initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
</sharedListeners >
<trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completion,

the same configuration given in my question worked. But, I had to increase the maxsizeofmessagetolog like

maxSizeOfMessageToLog="200000"

Answer (score 1):

set logMessagesAtTransportLevel=true to view encrypted messages

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

".."secure messages are logged as encrypted at this level.." - based on this, I thought logMessageAtTransportLevel will log message encrypted. But still I enabled both 
  logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
  logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
and still getting only encrypted messages in log.

Comment: thanks Yaron for looking into this, finally logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" worked.